# Symlink /var/www directory

Tags: apache2, symbolic-link

I have been trying to create a symlink:

> /var/www -> /home/USER/code/

Following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104337/create-a-symbolic-link-of-directory-in-ubuntu , I entered the following command:

> sudo ln -s /var/www /home/USER/code

However the result isn't what I expect. My link is stored inside the /www directory instead of linking the www directory itself. I use apache as the local web server, for my case, i have to access my code as

> localhost/code/PROJECT

whereas I wish to have something like

> localhost/PROJECT

The `code` directory should just serve as a directory where I store all my projects.

Anything I'm missing out?

Comment: Did you delete the `www` directory?  It'll create a symlink inside www if www exists.  It should create a symlink called www if www does not exist.

Comment: No `www` is there intact. Symlink inside the `www` directory doesn't serve the purpose I mentioned

Comment: You can't have two entries with the same name (a directory and a symlink in your case) in the same directory. What would you mean when you say /var/www/file.txt? You have to decide...

Comment: You should re-read @Shah's comment... you need to delete `www` and then create the symlink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete (or move, for safety) the `www` directory before you create the symlink.

So, you should have a `/var`, but there should be no `/var/www`.  Then, and only then, will a symlink called `www` be created that points to your localhost/code/project folder.

Comment: this accepted answer is wrong, first of all you say "delete" or "move" while we are talking about commands so you should put the respective shell command as well. Secondly he has the source and destination wrong in the ln command!

Comment: -1 for answering the question that wasn't asked and not pointing out the actual problem the user was suffering from.

Answer (score 35):

I think you have the `ln -s` 'source' and 'target' the wrong way round

---

**WRONG**:

`sudo ln -s /var/www /home/USER/code`

---

### **RIGHT:**

`sudo ln -s  /home/USER/code /var/www`

---

you will end up  with a symlink in your `/home/USER/code` folder pointing to `var/www` which is wrong.

For example, I have a folder for sally's site in `/home/webs/sallybydesign/`

```
cd /var/www
```

There should be no folder or file called `sallybydesign` in `/var/www` because we are about to make one.

```
 sudo ln -s  /home/ndmaque/webs/sallybydesign /var/www/sallybydesign
```

to see the new file (a symbolic link)

```
ls -l
```

you will see a file called `sallybydesign`, it is a symlink to your `home/webs/sallybydesign` folder and if you run

```
ls sallybydesign/
```

you will see the files in your `home/webs/sallybydesign` folder.

If so you can point your vhost file at `/var/www/sallybydesign` and it will automagically inherit all the apache `/var/www` permissions and solve a shed load of issues.

Comment: Did something change in the symbolic linking the last couple of updates to Ubuntu? I can't seem to do the symlinkning anymore and I get the famous 403 error.

Comment: @Daniel so do I

Comment: The permissions are not automatically inherited by default. Make sure to `chmod 0755 -R` on `sallybydesign` in the example above to allow the webserver to read. Also, you have to `AllowOverride All` in the default directory for / (usually in apache.conf).

Comment: ls sally/, got `Too many levels of symbolic links`.

Comment: In order to remember in which order it should be written, I simply use the same order as `cp`.